# PHP OOP - Autoinitiate objects

Tags: php, oop

```
<?php function __autoload($class_name)
{
  include_once 'inc/classes/class.' . $class_name . '.inc.php';
}


?>
```

Right now im using __autoload to automatic load up my classes whenever they are used. But i was thinking, why not automatic initiate the object themself as well, so you dont have to start the object in the pages itself, you could just call the properties of an class without starting the object.

But here i am stuck, i thought i could just do like the example below but its not working, objects are not starting.

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name)
{
  include_once 'inc/classes/class.' . $class_name . '.inc.php';
  '$'.$class_name = new $class_name;
 }


 ?>
```

Comment: If you type `new MyClass()` and the class **is not defined** then the `__autoload` is invoked so that the definition could be obtained. Why would you perform `new MyClass()` inside the autoloader again then? Are you caught in a thinking-infinite-loop maybe?

Comment: That would break both the principles of autoloading and having class files. A class file should just, well, hold the code for one class. Instantiation should happen elsewhere. Worth noting then, that classes are not just collection of methods - for that you would use simple namespaced functions.

Comment: I am no expert in this, just starting OOP but my thinking was since autoloading only includes the class files that are beeing called, why not just make it start the actual object as well? So in your websites you can cleanly just call the properties like <?php echo $user->name; ?> instead of <?php $user = new user; echo $user->name; ?>

Comment: From your example, I'm not sure you understand how this works. I will say though that you can do this `echo (new User())->name;`

Comment: Because _classes_ and _objects_ are different things. A class should not be aware, of when any instances of it are created.

Comment: Why shouldnt it be aware? Maybe its dumb question, but the whole __autoload function is about calling classes when they are called upon. If i use the user class, it loads the user class automaticly. Why not create an object at the same time? So whenever i want to access an property of a user class, the user class is automaticly loaded and the object for it is ready to be used. Maybe its another way of doing this.

Comment: What if you have two `User`s? Which one should be instantiated? : )) And what if `User` depends on the existence of other classes, that depend on the existence of other classes...You are basically misusing classes as containers of functions: for that, namespace would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not make sense. As you say, autoloading happens when the class is referenced.

How is it referenced? Let's see:

1. With `$object = new TheClassName()` - there you already have your instance. Why create another one automagically?
2. With static method calls, access to static properties or constants `TheClassName::I_NEED_THIS_CONSTANT` - why would I need an automagically created instance if I access a static method/property/constant?
3. With calls to `class_exists()` - why would I need an automagially created instance if I just want to check if the class exists?

Comment: I had a light lit up in my head when i tried to explain to myself what was going on. __AutoLoad and the new spl_autoload_register only happens when i reference the class. And i was not doing it, i was trying to make that automatic but there is no need for it. Static methods are basicly what i wanted. <?php echo user::$name ?> Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$$class_name = new $class_name();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using {}. In your example it will be:

```
${$class_name} = new $class_name;
```

With ${} you can create dynamic variables like that:

```
$i = '1';
${'tmp' . $i} = 'Hello world';
echo $tmp1; // Hello world
```

You should also use spl_autoload_register instead of __autoload (because it can be deprecated or removed in the future).

Comment: Does not work, not starting the object. Right now i have a class.user.inc.php but its not starting the user object.

Comment: What is the name of the class?